# Built in HTTP Server in Apache CXF

Tags: rest, jersey, cxf, httpserver

Is there an built in HTTP server in Apache CXF like "HttpServerFactory" of Jersey?
I tried reading through the CXF documentation but couldn't find anything similar.

Comment: Because that would duplicate what you can use Jetty for…?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is.

If you want JAX-RS service deployed on built-in server use `org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean`. Example usage (taken from [CXF samples](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/cxf/tags/cxf-2.7.8/distribution/src/main/release/samples/jax_rs/basic/src/main/java/demo/jaxrs/server/Server.java)):

```
JAXRSServerFactoryBean sf = new JAXRSServerFactoryBean();
sf.setResourceClasses(CustomerService.class);
sf.setResourceProvider(CustomerService.class, 
    new SingletonResourceProvider(new CustomerService()));
sf.setAddress("http://localhost:9000/");

sf.create();
```

If you want JAX-WS service deployed on built-in server you can use javax.xml.ws.Endpoint.publish(..). Sample code (again copied from [CXF Sample](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/cxf/tags/cxf-2.7.8/distribution/src/main/release/samples/java_first_jaxws/src/main/java/demo/hw/server/Server.java)):

```
    HelloWorldImpl implementor = new HelloWorldImpl();
    String address = "http://localhost:9000/helloWorld";
    Endpoint.publish(address, implementor);
```

Both JAX-WS and JAX-RS require adding `org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty` to classpath.

I really recommend taking look at [CXF samples](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/sample-projects.html). Sometimes they are indispensable.